# How to delete domain from laptop through cmd prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, domain, login-screen, domain-security

Hi I just brought a latitude 5330 laptop and when I charged it up and turned it on it is locked to a domain.
I have the login details for the local account but there is no where to log in to it on log in screen.
How do I delete the domain from laptop through command prompt and switch to Windows log in.

Comment: How are you getting to the command prompt?

Comment: have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-computer?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: If you are stuck, reinstall Windows fresh.

Comment: I'm getting to command prompt via a usb when I try to do a Windows install, it comes back with I can't install Windows on this as it's only coming up with usb and no disks

Answer (score 0):

Local and domain accounts use the same fields in the login screen, as internally the computer is its own domain. To use a local account, enter its username as **`.\User`** (the `.` being shorthand for the local computer's name).